# Nginx express Ubuntu net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: nginx, express, handlebars

В общем на локальной машине все работало в IDE.
Как перенес на сервер - никак.
Nginx на 80 порту проксит на порт node.
Страницу грузит, но стили никак не грузятся... `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.`

Движок express Handlebars.
В главном app.js использовал:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
```

Тупо не видит css файлы.... уже все возможные пути перебрал в `<link rel="stylesheet">`

Причем без движка Handlebars (до этого) другой сайт работал норм (но там вообще все просто было).

Как будто Nginx не проксит нормально и соединение рвется.

Памагите.)))

Вот конфиг Nginx

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
events{}

http {
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        sendfile on;
                                  }

        server {

                server_name 192.168.128.115;

        location / {

                        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                        proxy_http_version 1.1;
                        proxy_set_header Host $host;
                        }

                }

        }
```

Comment: nginx -T сможете показать?

Comment: Готово)) У меня идет проверка авторизации при входе на сайт. Если не авторизован, то на страницу логина  ```192.168.128.115/login/```

Comment: Первое, что стоит попробовать - это перенести include /etc/nginx/mime.types под location. Еще net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED наталкивает на мысль, что где-то есть конфликт между http и https, может быть где то в пути к файлам написан один протокол, а сервер работает на другом? Плюс к этому может быть проблема с правами доступа к каталогу, где лежат файлы. Исправляется через chmod

Comment: Вот я тоже обратил внимание, что ```style.css``` ищет по ```https://```. ```https://192.168.128.115/public/css/style_2.css```, хотя естствнно у меня ```http```. Хотя страницу берет по ```GET``` нормально ```http://192.168.128.115/login```. Права все 777.

Comment: Попробуйте listen 80 добавить под server

Comment: Да там то все слушается. Я прихожу на саму страницу... Стили не грузятся...

Comment: А у Вас страница открывается по https? если нет, то и стили не подгрузятся, так как Вы сами сказали, что они пытаются отдаться через https

Comment: Да вот в том и дело... что страница открывается по ```http```, а ```css``` ищется по ```https```... и что в этом случае предпринять))) И не понятно почему вообще по https идет искать и не переходит на http

Answer (score 0):

Дело оказалось в пакете helmet, он изменял каким-то образом заголовки и получалась байда.